# Cant change DOM element in Node JS? Jsdom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, dom

I am incredibly confused - new to Node JS here. I am trying to change a DOM element (by class, name, etc) within index.js, my Node js main file.

I read the docs on the module jsdom that supposedly can get/change elements in html, because in node this does not work: `var cb = document.getElementsByName('field206451')[0];`

Following other questions and installing jsdom, I now get the error:

```
TypeError: jsdom.env is not a function
```

When trying this:

```
app.get('/changePage', function (request, response) {

fs.readFile(__dirname +"/views/pages/index.ejs", 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    jsdom.env(data, [], function (errors, window) {
        var $ = require('jquery')(window);
        $("p").each(function () {
            var content = $(this).text();
            console.log(content);
            $(this).text(content + " modified!");
        });

    });
});

    response.end("works");
});
```

I have no idea what I am doing here. Why doesn't it recognize js dom and how can I change the value of say a p in node?

Side note - my "html" file is actually an index.ejs

Comment: are you... trying to change html that is already rendered in the browser, from node.js? because that's not how this works. that's not how any of this works!

Answer (score 1):

**Node.js** is an open-source, cross-platform JavaScript run-time environment for executing JavaScript code server-side.

Previously, JavaScript was used primarily for client-side scripting, in which scripts written in JavaScript are embedded in a webpage's HTML, to be run client-side by a JavaScript engine in the user's web browser.

Node.js enables JavaScript to be used for server-side scripting, and runs scripts server-side to produce dynamic web page content before the page is sent to the user's web browser.

[Reference Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)

As stated above, **the purpose is to produce dynamic web page content before the page is sent to user's browser**

So, the page hasn't reached client's browser yet, so DOM is not initialized yet, and so document is nothing in that server side script.

I Hope that clears your confusion. You are doing something in the environment which the environment is not meant for.

Comment: ok. got it. But then what if the user types in a text field, hits enter, and that text is supposed to appear in a label within the document? Wasn't the page reloaded? If Node JS cant accomplish this, how would one do this? An additional js file?

Comment: If you want to get this kind of behavior, you can either send parameter in request and from server render page with entered value showing in a label. 
The better approach will be to use front end JS framework like Angular JS for this purpose. They both combine quiet interestingly.

Comment: Is this how most developers do this kind of thing, in place of using php? what would you do? Do you have an example of doing this?

Comment: Yes I think both frameworks are easy to learn as all are Javascript. I think you can learn those quickly from tutorials given on internet.